# How To Determine The Radius of This Power Series

Tags: power-series

$$ \sum_{n\ge 0} (3+\cos n)x^n   ; a_n = (3+\cos n) $$
I used d'Alembert : $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n} = \lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{3+\cos(n+1)}{3+\cos n} $$
Nw I'm stuck With How To get Rid Of "cosine" functions which Doesn't have limits at infinity ; a Hint Pleaze

Comment: The limit you're after does not exist. Also, use $\to$ instead of $->$.

Comment: how so , it certainly has a Radius But how to find it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Root test:
$$\sqrt[n]{|(3+\cos n)x^n|}\to |x|$$
because
$$2\le(3+\cos n)\le 4\implies \sqrt[n]{2}\le\sqrt[n]{(3+\cos n)}\le\sqrt[n]{4}.$$
So the radius is 1.

Comment: thank you Very Much ; 
So I think D'ALmebert Doesn't Work with Some trigonometrics a_n